# Bash split a space-delimited string into a variable number of substrings

Tags: string, bash

Suppose I have two space-delimited strings in my bash script, which are

```
permitted_hosts="node1 node2 node3"
```

and

```
runs_list="run1 run2 run3 run4 run5"
```

These respectively represent the list of permitted hosts and the list of runs to execute.  So, I need to run each of the runs in `$runs_list` on 1 of the hosts in `$permitted_hosts`.

What I'd like to do is divide `$runs_list` into `$N` substrings, where `$N` is the number of elements in `$permitted_hosts` and where each of the `$N` substrings is mapped to a different element in `$permitted_hosts`.

If that's confusing, then consider this concrete workaround solution.  For the exact given values of `$permitted_hosts` and `$runs_list` above, the following bash script checks the current host, and if the current host is in `$permitted_hosts`, then it launches the runs in `$runs_list` that are associated with the current host.  Of course, this script doesn't use the variables `$permitted_hosts` and `$runs_list`, but it achieves the desired effect for the given example.  What I'm really trying to do is modify the code below so that I can modify the values of variables `$permitted_hosts` and `$runs_list` and it will work appropriately.

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname=$(hostname)
if [ "$hostname" == "node1" ]; then
    runs="run1 run2"
elif [ "$hostname" == "node2" ]; then
    runs="run3 run4"
elif [ "$hostname" == "node3" ]; then
    runs="run5"
else
    echo "ERROR: Invoked on invalid host ('$hostname')! Aborting." 
    exit 0
fi

for run in $runs; do
    ./launch $run
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, firstly — instead of space-delimited strings, you should probably use arrays:

```
permitted_hosts=(node1 node2 node3)
runs_list=(run1 run2 run3 run4 run5)
```

If you have to start out with space-delimited strings, you can at least convert them to arrays:

```
permitted_hosts=($permitted_hosts_str)
runs_list=($runs_list_str)
```

That out of the way . . . basically you have two steps: (1) convert the hostname into an integer representing its position in `permitted_hosts`:

```
hostname="$(hostname)"
num_hosts="${#permitted_hosts[@]}"      # for convenience

host_index=0
while true ; do
    if [[ "${permitted_hosts[host_index]}" = "$hostname" ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    (( ++host_index ))
    if (( host_index > num_hosts )) ; then
        printf 'ERROR: Invoked on invalid host ('%s')! Aborting.\n' "$hostname" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
# host_index is now an integer index into permitted_hosts
```

and (2) convert this integer into an appropriate subset of `runs_list`:

```
num_runs="${#runs_list[@]}"      # for convenience
for (( run_index = host_index ; run_index < num_runs ; run_index += num_hosts )) ; do
    ./launch "${runs_list[run_index]}"
done
```

So, for example, if you have *H* hosts, then host #0 will launch run #0, run #*H*, run #2*H*, etc.; host #1 will launch run #1, run #*H*+1, run #2*H*+1, etc.; and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I *knew* there had to be a better way :)